# Can't connect to greenplum with error message : "no pg_hba.conf entry"

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I'm using gp 4.3.7.2, and I followed the manual http://120.52.72.46/gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/c3pr90ntcsf0/gs/43/pdf/GPDB43xGettingStarted.pdf

I can connect to server with admin user, but when I try to use another user, I get the error message

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gpuser", database "rdw", SSL off
```

I've already done some research on stackoverflow. I modified the `pg_hba.conf`, add an entry

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

and then reload the config file with `gpstop -u` and `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`, even tried to restart the gp server. But I still get the same error.

I also tried other entries like

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

this didn't work too.

Please tell me how to fix this.

edit:

I reinstalled the database in single node mode and followed exactly the manual mentioned before. I create two users : user1, user2 and grant role `users` to these two users.
What I executed:
In command line:

```
$ createuser -P user1
Enter password for new role:
Enter it again:
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
```

In psql:

```
=# CREATE USER user2 WITH PASSWORD 'changeme' CREATEDB NOSUPERUSER;    
=# CREATE ROLE users;
=# GRANT users TO user1, user2;
```

Here is my whole pg_hba.conf, which is located at `/data/gp/server/master/gpsne-1/pg_hba.conf`. I add the last 3 lines.

```
local    all         hadoop         ident
host     all         hadoop         127.0.0.1/28    trust
host     all         hadoop         10.10.10.32/32       trust
host     all         hadoop         ::1/128       trust
host     all         hadoop         fe80::d6ae:52ff:feb9:87c2/128       trust
local    replication hadoop         ident
host     replication hadoop         samenet       trust
local tutorial +users md5
local tutorial +users 127.0.0.1/28 md5
hostssl tutorial +users samenet md5
```

But I still get the same error.

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "user1", database "tutorial", SSL off
```

When I installed the database, I got a warning message, not sure if it is related.

```
20160302:10:44:51:023434 gpinitsystem:bobcat04:hadoop-[WARN]:-Host 127.0.0.1 is assigned as localhost in /etc/hosts
20160302:10:44:51:023434 gpinitsystem:bobcat04:hadoop-[WARN]:-This will cause segment->master communication failures
20160302:10:44:51:023434 gpinitsystem:bobcat04:hadoop-[WARN]:-Remove 127.0.0.1 from local host line in /etc/hosts
```

Comment: The entry you've added seems correct. The problem must be somewhere else. Maybe you changed a wrong 'pg_hba.conf' file, or didn't restart the server.

Comment: "[local]" as in Unix Domain Socket? This requires "local" instead of "host".

Comment: Please post your entire pg_hba.conf, but without the comments.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum thank you for your advice, I provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in the 2nd last line:

```
local tutorial +users 127.0.0.1/28 md5
```

There should not be an IP address listed for local connections.

Did you run `gpstop -u` to reload after making the changes?
I suspect the reload failed due to the invalid line.

Remove the line and run `gpstop -u` again and try to connect again.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the line and it works! But the GP getting started manual says to add that entry...I will report this to Pivotal.

Answer (score 0):

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "gpuser", database "rdw", SSL off
```

This means you are trying to connect to Greenplum from the master host using psql and without specifying the hostname.  If you just type this:

```
psql
```

The psql client will attempt to connect to the LOCAL instance of Greenplum.  The pg_hba.conf entry you added was for HOST authentication, not LOCAL.

You can fix this by doing one of two things.

1. When using psql and you want to authenticate with a HOST entry from the pg_hba.conf file, add the -h option.  This tells the client to connect to Greenplum and authenticate with the host entry.

   ```
   psql -h mdw
   ```
2. You can also add an entry to the bottom of the pg_hba.conf file like this:

   ```
   local all all md5
   ```

   or if you trust everyone locally

   ```
   local all all trust
   ```

More information on the pg_hba.conf file is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this doesn't solve my problem :( Please see more information I add to the question.